# Input attributes not visible via onclick event

Tags: javascript, radio-button, pug

I have a simple radio button form in jade/pug view like this:

```
form
  input(type='radio',id="0", group="group0", value="some string" my_prop="hello", onclick='radioClick(this)')
```

In my js script, I have defined `radioClick` function like this:

```
function radioClick(e){
  console.log(e)
  console.log(e.my_prop)
  console.log(e.group)
  console.log(e.type)
  console.log(e.id)
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
<input type="radio" my_prop="hello" group="0" id="0" value="some string" onclick="radioClick(this)">
undefined //<--- Why are these undefined?
undefined //<--- Why are these undefined?
radio
0
```

Why are the attributes `group` and `my_prop` undefined? How can I access them when the event onclick is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getAttribute() and place the desired attribute in the string.

```js
function radioClick(e){
  console.log(e.getAttribute('my_prop'));
  console.log(e.getAttribute('group'));
  console.log(e.getAttribute('type'));
  console.log(e.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" my_prop="hello" group="0" id="0" value="some string" onclick="radioClick(this)">
```

Comment: That works! why are some attributes accessible and others not?